# How does docker manage hashes for forking of docker images?

Tags: hash, docker, dockerhub

In docker, its clear that i can pull other people's images and run them.

But somehow, docker seems to know if i've ever pushed a layer , and is able to skip pushing that image. I thus have two questions :

- How does dockerhub store image hashes - are the image hashes shared between docker users , or local to a given user ?  That is , is it capable of forking an image from "user a" on to  "user b" ? Or does "user a" have his own unique set of hashes...?  And furthermore, what happens if "user a" removes his original image - will "user b"'s image be compromised - or does dockerhub store images permanantly ?
- Is there any chance of collision between image hashes ?

For clarity ive created a diagram of the particular question im curious about.  In this diagram, is jims_images permanantly dependent on bobs_image?  What if bob deletes his dockerhub account?

[image: Diagram of the question im asking: how does docker compute dockerhub_jims_image? What if bobs account is deleted?]

Answer (score -1):

No, I don't think `jims_images` permanantly dependent on `bobs_image`.

If you want to achieve this, better to docker way to use `Dockerfile` for `jims_images`.

```
FROM bobs_image
```

Then each time, if you rebuild the image (auto in dockerhub), then it will kepp dependance